# Play framework: listing routes from Router

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using PlayFramework 2.5.X (Scala) and I'm trying to list the routes binded from the routes file. I noticed that with Guice you can inject the current Router like this:

```
class Sample @Inject()(implicit val ec: ExecutionContext,
                       implicit val mat: Materializer,
                       router : Router)
```

However, it looks I can't access to any routes `Seq` or something like that. Or at least not in an easy way. I've been searching for a while and found nothing but I'm pretty sure there should be a way to access to this information. Can someone shed some light here?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? There is `Router#documentation`, but that is for informational purposes.

Comment: In short words I would like to have a Filter to verify some security constraints over endpoint-method pairs. That's the reason I'd like to have some kind of Seq, Map... with the routes info.

Comment: If it is for authentication / authorization, have you considered using a library such as deadbolt, pac4j, silhouette...?